# Wireless Drivers/Aeroplane mode stuck on

Tags: drivers, wireless

this is my first time using Ubuntu so forgive me if I seem a bit of an idiot when going through this.

Firstly I had an issue with the Aeroplane mode being stuck on and was saying "Use hardware switch to turn off". However I only have one key to do this which has no effect.

So I read that this could be a driver issue so I've been trying to install drivers for RT3290 wireless card.

For this I've been using "DP0_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508" (which I've seen recommended by many sources)

However with this, a step involved is the console command

```
make
sudo make install
```

After using "make" the following errors come up at the end:

```
In function ‘memcpy’,
    inlined from ‘rt_ioctl_iwaplist’ at /home/ben/Desktop/WIFI_Patches/DP0_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:700:2:
./include/linux/string.h:305:4: error: call to ‘__read_overflow2’ declared with attribute error: detected read beyond size of object passed as 2nd parameter
    __read_overflow2();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:302: recipe for target '/home/ben/Desktop/WIFI_Patches/DP0_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ben/Desktop/WIFI_Patches/DP0_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o] Error 1
Makefile:1546: recipe for target '_module_/home/ben/Desktop/WIFI_Patches/DP0_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ben/Desktop/WIFI_Patches/DP0_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic'
Makefile:380: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :D

**EDIT**

This is the result from rfkill list all:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

when using rfkill unblock wifi it has no effect.

The laptop is a HP pavilion Model "11-n012na"

Comment: It isn't a driver issue. This old circa-2012 driver isn't going to move the switch. May we see: `rfkill list all` What brand and model laptop is it? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I will update the question with some more details :)

Comment: The `Hard blocked: yes` part of the output means that there is a Physical Switch on your laptop that is in the "Wifi:OFF" position.  Check the manufacturer's specifications for the laptop to findout there this Physical Switch is located. Using your finger, move it to the other position.

Comment: I know it looks this way and this is why I'm having the issue as there is no physical switch. There is a button on the keyboard however this doesnt have any effect (which it normally would when windows was installed)

Answer (score 0):

Is the module `hp-wmi` loaded? Check:

```
lsmod | grep wmi
```

If it is loaded, try removing it:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

If this is helpful, I will edit the answer to add instructions to make it permanent.

It has been suggested that resetting the BIOS to defaults is sometimes helpful to get the airplane mode button to function. Please try it.

If none of these steps are helpful, I suggest that you file a bug against hp-wmi: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/

Finally, there are even more drastic steps: http://madwifi-project.org/wiki/UserDocs/MiniPCI

Comment: Tried your first suggestion and it was loaded however removing it didnt help :/ in terms of the BIOS I'm having trouble accessing it, the pc loads straight up to ubuntu without time to press any key (I've tried). When I had win10 on, I had to go into the settings to do advanced startup :/

Comment: HPs are very troublesome due to, I assume, a defect in hp-wmi. There are quite a few cases here and on ubuntuforums.org with your same problem and no solution.

Comment: So basically I just shouldnt use ubuntu XD

Comment: Since hp-wmi is more or less common across all of Linux, I'd be very surprised if any Linux distribution would work. If you find one, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found that <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> turned on the WiFi.
I don't know how I got into that state, but the function key corrected the WiFi state issue.