# my wireless adapter is hard blocked . output for the command "sudo lshw -class network" is how to enable my wifi?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hardware, ralink

```
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: ec:0e:c4:6f:39:57
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.10.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b2510000-b251ffff
```

---

```
ram@ram-HP-15-Notebook-PC / $ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
ram@ram-HP-15-Notebook-PC / $ 
ram@ram-HP-15-Notebook-PC / $ lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap -e acpi
hp_wmi                 16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    77824  21 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_soc_sst_acpi
sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,hp_wmi
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of two terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap -e acpi` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: i have edited the result please check it out and help me

Comment: Please see and try these steps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/983565/wireless-drivers-aeroplane-mode-stuck-on/983574#983574