# Ubuntu is unable to start Wifi (hardblocked)

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I am having Ubuntu 16.06LTS and Hp pavilion  laptop. And not able to start Wi-Fi.  I have used many solutions which are already given on the forum like, 
1. rfkill unblock all 
2. Removing /dev/rfkill and restarting
But none of them worked.

rfkill list shows below output, 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
             Soft blocked: no
             Hard blocked: yes

Thanks in advance

Comment: What wifi card is this and what driver are you currently using for it?

Comment: Wifi  card Ralink Corp.  RT3290 wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Comment: Is the Wifi Interface being managed by NetworkManager?

Comment: In setting -> network then Airplane mode is already  on..  If I off it and close tab and reopen, then again it change to ON status automatically.. And wireless on off button  is not working

Answer (score 0):

HP laptops use a module *hp-wmi* to translate key presses into action; in your case, turn off the hard block and turn on the wireless.

Let’s troubleshoot your problem.

First, check to see if the module *hp-wmi* is loaded.

```
lsmod | grep hp
```

If so, remove it:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Any improvement?

Comment: Sorry for late comment. It is still showing the same error

Comment: Any further suggestion?

Comment: Please see my answer and the following comments here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/983565/wireless-drivers-aeroplane-mode-stuck-on Aside from trying the daily build of Ubuntu 18.04 to see if the bug in hp-wmi is resolved, I haven't any other suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: I have reset the BIOS and it had started, but after 5 mins the problem started again.