# Airplane Mode ON - use hardware switch to turn off

Tags: wireless, airplane-mode

Wifi not working in my HP Laptop. It's always on in airplane MODE. rfkill not working anymore. Please HELP if there is other way or something. I really tired on other solution found in internet. HELP Me Please. Thank You.
[image: rfkill result]

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/983565/wireless-drivers-aeroplane-mode-stuck-on/983574#983574

Comment: Not working. Here is the result:

(snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd                    86016  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof)

Comment: Please confirm the manual switch is in the ON position.

Comment: try ''sudo nmcli radio wifi on''

Answer (score 2):

My wifi is also disabled after installing Ubuntu on an HP Pavilion laptop, I found that the touch switch that turns my wifi on and off now toggles it into and out of airplane mode. I think that is the manual switch it is talking about. At least it was for me.

Answer (score 1):

My Dell Inspiron was experiencing the same issue with defaulting to airplane mode. Pressing the WiFi hardware button disables airplane mode and allows you to procede to switch on WiFi

Answer (score 0):

It took me about 3 days to work on it after installation, and I finally solved it. I reset all the settings to the default values on the hardware BIOS screen. Then when I rebooted the computer, it worked out right away. I proceeded with an all-in-one desktop computer, but with a laptop, I think there are some other solutions. For example, turning off the fast boot on partitioned Windows, physically removing the battery...

```
$ sudo rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to just use the same command with super user

> $ sudo rfkill list all

after that just suspend your system by clicking on "Power off/ Log out"

NOTE:-"make it sure that you will suspending it not powering it off"

and again just login by entering a password

open terminal

enter

> $ rfkill list all

and you can see the status of
"Wireless lan"
Soft blocked:no
hard blocked:no

now check once